# ionic android unexpected token

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic Framework to build a mobile app for Android/iOS. I was able 
to build the project for android (ionic build android). When I run the app, it will be only a white screen, that's because there is an error (when you use GapDebug, you can run apps on your phone and you will be able to debug, and see errors). Now if I run it on the desktop browser there really is NO error and everything is working. Below is the error that is shown in GapDebug: [image: error]

Now when you check the code in service.js line 394:
[image: code]

There's nothing wrong with the code right? If I try to change line 394 to something like `key : self.currentUser`, there will be NO error and the app will work. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: After line 392 try to debug what childQuestionSnapshot is. Does it have a key called 'key' ?

Comment: Yes it has. I even tried putting childQuestionSnapshot.key in a variable and having the variable be inside the brackets. The same error occurs on the bracketed part (syntax error).

Comment: Please try remote debugging using some android device then you can get idea about the issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead

```
var updateObj = {};
updateObj[childQuestionSnapshot.key] = self.currentUser;
applicantRef.update(updateObj, function() {
    console.log("applicant answers updated");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are making an object's attribute a list? If you want the key to be **childQuestionSnapshot.key** then remove the square brackets.

If you are trying to update a list of objects, you can do something similar to the below:

```js
var test = [{key: 'thisguy'},{key: 'thatguy'},{key: 'myguy'}]
test.forEach(function(item){
 item['key']='newguy'
})
console.log(test)
```

Comment: The value of childQuestionSnapshot.key is what I need, the key is uniquely generated by Firebase (the database I'm using). I don't need the 'key' itself so I can't do something like childQuestionSnapshot['key']. What I'm trying to do is for example, 'someUniqueKey631xkjs4k2' : self.currentUser, I am updating the database that has the key someUniqueKey631xkjs4k2.

Comment: You need brackets when you want the value of the variable as the key of the object, and not the variable name itself.

Comment: Ok so I did this, updateObj[childQuestionSnapshot.key] = self.currentUser; and pass the updateObj in the applicantRef.update instead and it worked! Didn't know updateObj[childQuestionSnapshot.key] would work.

Comment: Cool, glad this worked out for ya! Sorry for the delayed response, was a bit busy yesterday!